# Find repeating characters in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to find a regex which finds 3 repeating characters appearing contiguously in a string. The character set could be alphabet, digit or any special character.

I wanted the first try for alphabet and digits and then extend the expression to include special characters. The ones I tried are. Both of these fail for the string "c2sssFg1". What am I doing wrong here?

```
(\\w*)\\2{3,}(\\w*)

(\\w*?)(\\w)\\2{3,}(\\w*)
```

I looked at some of the examples on SO and on web but I didn't find the right solution that passes the random strings I test.
Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: What about `(\w)\1{2}`? Obviously escaping the backslashes with a second one.

Comment: Should have said at least 3 repeating characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(.)\1{2}
```

(.) matches any char

\1 matches that exactly char

{2} is to grant its 2 more of that

Comment: Looks like this worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(.)\1\1`. It works for general case.